# Not being redirected to razor view and instead seeing snapshot page using servicestack 5.1

Tags: servicestack

1. I have made a self hosting console application. 
   -- added  Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat()); in configuration
   -- added a default.cshtml in the same project.
2. Added an empty .Net project and added folder for DTO, service and views.
   -- added a _Layout.cshtml page and Hello.cshtml page in Views folder.
   -- added below route in DTO file

   ```
    [Route("/hello")]
     public class Hello : IReturn<HelloResponse>
     {
     }

     public class HelloResponse
     {
        public string Msg { get; set; }
     }
   ```

   -- added below service method in services

   ```
       public HelloResponse Any(Hello rqeuest)
       {
           return new HelloResponse { Msg = "Hi!!" };
       }
   ```

On accessing http://localhost:port/hello 
I see the snapshot page instead of my Hello.cshtml page.

I am on Servicestack 5.1, also I have set properties of cshtml page to Copy if newer.

Can you please guide on what could be wrong ?

Comment: Can you create a stand-alone project on GitHub which repro's this issue.